# Can't get this overly complicated loop to work correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts, if-statement

So I'm editing the index.php in my WP theme's folder, essentially what I want it to do is this:

- Show 4 Posts on first page of blog.
- Style the first (newest) post on the first page differently. Style the other 3 the same.
- Show 6 Posts on every other paginated page.

Here's the loop I'm working with, the first page appears fine, but for some reason on page 2 and higher it's executing really weird and showing only **one** post on each additional page. Also, it will only show the title and not the date or excerpt. Here's my code:

```
           <?php 
            if( is_home() && !is_paged() ){
            global $query_string;
            parse_str( $query_string, $args );
            $args['posts_per_page'] = 4;
            query_posts($args);
            if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
           if (++$counter == 1) { ?>
            <div class="featured_post">
                <p class="date"><?php the_date('M j, Y'); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featuredblog'); ?></a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="regular_post">
                <p class="date"><?php the_date('M j, Y'); ?></p>
                <div class="postimage"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('regularblog'); ?></a></div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php
                    // short_title($after, $length)
                    echo short_title('...', 7);
                    ?></h3></a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile;
        else :
           // Code for no posts found here
        endif;
        } else {
            global $query_string;
            parse_str( $query_string, $args );
            $args['posts_per_page'] = 6;
            query_posts($args); ?>
            <div class="regular_post">
                <p class="date"><?php the_date('M j, Y'); ?></p>
                <div class="postimage"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('regularblog'); ?></a></div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Maybe there's too many if...else statements in there?

Comment: now go and pick an answer because 50% is TOO low

Comment: So, I figured it out. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (is_home() && !is_paged() ) {
                global $query_string;
                parse_str( $query_string, $args );
                $args['posts_per_page'] = 4;
                query_posts($args);
                } else { 
                global $query_string;
                parse_str( $query_string, $args );
                $args['posts_per_page'] = 6;
                query_posts($args);
                } ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post<?php echo ++$counter; ?>">
                    <?php if ( is_home() && !is_paged() && $counter == 1 ) { ?>
                        do stuff
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        do other stuff
                    <?php } ?> 
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some kind of framework? that's a pretty bad tempalte engine.

Anyway if yuo need to add style, you should leave the job to CSS.

if you need extremly precision you can just leave a class with a counter for each element you need to style differently.

like `<div class="Element<?php echo ++$counter; ?>"></div>`

and then you can add your styles in CSS

```
.Element1,.Element2,.Element3 {styles}
.Element4 {other styles}
```

in this way you simplify the life with your php code

Keep in mind one day you will not even need to add a class counter.. In the near future you could use the `nth-child css selector` http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Edit: damn me I replied someone with 50% AR

Comment: he's using wordpress, and thus the wordpress template engine.  i think you'll find alot of people that disagree with your dislike of it. ;)

Comment: the backend code and plugins are very well structured.  the template engine can be quite clean.  i think you'll find any tool can be misused.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would follow yes123, but really leave it all to css.  basically, all of your posts should be wrapped in a parent div, and each should be classed the same way.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that's about what you should resolve to, with more tags in the post, obviously.

from there, the way to style the first post differently would be using the `#content > .post:first-child` selector.

also, having a different number of posts per page is probably not a good idea.  i've actually never really tried it, but i can see where the paging would get screwed up, and you'd probably never see posts 5 or 6.  i'm thinking wordpress would probably say that with 6 posts per page, page 2 should always start with post 7.  not positive though.

Comment: I understand the power of CSS and realize that I can do it this way. Only problem is, I can't get 4 to show on the first page and have 6 on the following page.

Comment: @nurain, i'm telling you i don't think you'll be able to do that and have a properly functioning site.  thats what my last paragraph is about.  and if you know you can do it with css, do it.  it'll clean up your code significantly, and maybe you'll figure out some magical way to page in wordpress.